# If $n\gt 2$ then there is a prime number $p$ such that $n\lt p\lt n!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm trying to prove that

> For all integers $n>2$ there is a prime number $p$ such that $n \lt p \lt n!$

I was trying to solve it by contradiction and supposed that $p\geq n$, then by definition of prime numbers, $p$ is a divisor of $n!.$  I am stuck here and wonder what would be my next step?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried modifying Euclid's proof that there are an infinite number of primes?

Comment: Assuming $p \le n$ won't do lead to a contradiction because there *are* primes less than or equal to n.(!!!)  You need to assume there are no primes between n+1 and n!-1. ... which... might not be the best approach.

Comment: What divides $n! -1$?

Comment: @fleablood: ah, that is the much more elegant argument...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For all $2< k \le n$ it follows that $k|n!$ so no $k | (n! -1)$.  So either $n!-1$ is prime or there is a prime number greater than $n$ that divides $n! -1$.

Either way there is a prime number between $n$ and $n!$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=3$ be our base case, then $p=5$ proves this case since $3\lt 5\lt 3!=6$.  Now suppose that the theorem is true for $2\lt n\le k$, and let $p_k$ be the smallest prime such that $p_k\gt k$.  Note this means that $p_k\ge 5$.  Consider the number

$$q = p_k\# +1 = 1+ \prod_{p\text{ is prime}\atop p\le p_k}p$$

Now consider the case $n = k+1$.  If $p_k \gt k+1$ then we are done.  Otherwise, we must have $p_k = k+1$.  Note that our number $q$ must be less than $(k+1)!$ since $4$ is not a factor of $q-1$.  Further, $q$ has no factors in common with any prime $\le p_k$, and therefore is either prime or has prime factors all of which are greater than $p_k$.  Therefore there must exist a prime $r$ such that $r\mid q$ and $k+1\lt r \lt (k+1)!$.